# Full size image in fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

how to show full sized images in fancybox?

Now, I'm using something like this:

```
$('.image').fancybox();
```

But fancybox resize original image to other sizes. For exmple if I have 960 X 350 it resizes it to 600 X 180. But I want original size. How to do this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `autoDimensions` option, which can be set to true.

> For inline and ajax views, resizes the view to the element recieves.
>   Make sure it has dimensions otherwise this will give unexpected
>   results

http://fancybox.net/api

Answer (score 0):

A newer solution is to include jquery.fancybox-button.css and jquery.fancybox-buttons.js to your project, and then to do something like this:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers: {
        buttons: {}
   }
});
```

This will add a bar of buttons at the top of the viewport. You can click on the resize button to have the viewport expand so that you can see the entire image rather than the viewport-sized version of the image.